# Unable to locate the api.php route file in Laravel 11

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-11

I am attempting to integrate Laravel 11 with React.js for data retrieval and transmission between the two. However, I cannot locate the `routes/api.php` file in the latest version of Laravel.

I have searched for others experiencing the same issue, but I have yet to find any similar cases since Laravel 11 was only released a week ago.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/routing#api-routes

If your application will also offer a stateless API, you may enable API routing using the `install:api` Artisan command:

```php
php artisan install:api
```

[...] In addition, the `install:api` command creates the `routes/api.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

You  enable api route

```
php artisan install:api
```

you can refer to this link:[enter link description here](https://medium.com/@1415sandalanka/routes-api-php-e23c902a8788)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78188252/14569750 ??